# how to navigate to new screen without setting routes in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm building a shopping app and I can create a category from the database! however, I'm having a problem on how to navigate to that new category without defining routes in main.dart

Comment: Well, I suggest you use named route. What's the problem with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you try this?

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen()),
);
```

Comment: this still sets a route

Answer (score 0):

Or, alternatively, you can use [onGenerateRoute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/onGenerateRoute.html) to define how your routing should work, and do whatever black magic you desire in this function. :-)